# how to Format input field with dash

Tags: apex, community

i am new to salesforce . i want to create a field with format 123-456-78-90 maximum limit of the field is 13 . i have tried with field update.But i want in Apex.

```
LEFT(SampleMask__c , 3) + '-' + 
MID(SampleMask__c , 4, 3) + '-' + 
MID(SampleMask__c , 6, 2) + '-' + 
RIGHT(SampleMask__c ,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your original input, it might go something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d{3})-?(\\d{3})-?(\\d{2})-?(\\d{2})');
Matcher m = p.matcher('1234567890'); // Put field to test here
if(m.find()) {
  String result = m.group(1)+'-'+m.group(2)+'-'+m.group(3)+'-'+m.group(4);
} else {
  // Display an error because the value did not match expected input.
}
```

Other methods are also possible, depending on your specific input. This specific pattern assumes there may be a dash between each value, so if something writes in "123-456-78-90" in the field, this code will still work.

Comment: hi if i give an input 1234-123-4511 means. it giving output as 234-123-45-11. please advice. the output have to come as 123-412-34-51